# How to pass data in tableview using swift 3?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I want to get, store & pass an URL in tableview to another table view in swift 3?

I am trying a lot but i can't do it? Please help me.

class EpisodesTableViewController: UITableViewController
{
    var episodes = Episode
    var audioPlayer : AVAudioPlayer!

```
var selectedVideoIndex: Int!


override func viewDidLoad()
{
    super.viewDidLoad()

    episodes = Episode.downloadAllEpisodes()
    self.tableView.reloadData()

    tableView.estimatedRowHeight = tableView.rowHeight
    tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
    tableView.separatorStyle = .none

}

override var preferredStatusBarStyle : UIStatusBarStyle {
    return .lightContent
}

// MARK: - Table view data source

override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int
{
    return 1
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int
{
    return episodes.count
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
{
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Episode Cell", for: indexPath) as! EpisodeTableViewCell
    let episode = episodes[indexPath.row]

    cell.episode = episode

    return cell
}

// MARK: - UITableViewDelegate

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath:
    IndexPath)
{
    tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true)

    performSegue(withIdentifier: "secondView", sender: indexPath.row)

}



override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {

    var next = segue.PViewController  as! PlayTableViewController

    next.index = sender as? Int
}
```

here is the another code

```
class PlayTableViewController: UITableViewController
```

{

```
var play = [PlayView]()
var audioPlayer : AVAudioPlayer!

var indexOfCell:Int?


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    super.viewDidLoad()

    play = PlayView.downloadAllEpisodes()
    self.tableView.reloadData()

    tableView.estimatedRowHeight = tableView.rowHeight
    tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
    tableView.separatorStyle = .none
}

override var preferredStatusBarStyle : UIStatusBarStyle {
    return .lightContent
}

override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int
{
    return 1
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int
{
    return play.count
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
{
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Player Cell", for: indexPath) as! PlayerTableViewCell
    let playV = play[indexPath.row]

    cell.PV = playV

    return cell
}


// MARK: - UITableViewDelegate

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath:
    IndexPath)
{
    tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true)

    let episode = play[indexPath.row]
    let player = AVPlayer(url: episode.url!)
    let playerViewController = AVPlayerViewController()
    playerViewController.player = player
    self.present(playerViewController, animated: true) {
        playerViewController.player!.play()
    }
}
```

}

class PlayView {

```
var name: String?
var thumbnailURL: URL?
var url: URL?

init(name: String, thumbnailURL: URL, url: URL)
{
    self.name = name
    self.thumbnailURL = thumbnailURL
    self.url = url
}

init(pvDictionary: [String : Any]) {
    self.name = pvDictionary["name"] as? String
    // url, createdAt, author, thumbnailURL
    url = URL(string: pvDictionary["alt_url"] as! String)
    thumbnailURL = URL(string: pvDictionary["alt_image"] as! String)
}

static func downloadAllEpisodes() -> [PlayView]
{
    var playView = [PlayView]()



    let url2 = URL(string: "http://nix2.iotabdapps.com/apk/items.json")
    let jsonData = try? Data(contentsOf: url2!)

    if let jsonDictionary = NetworkService.parseJSONFromData(jsonData) {
        let pvDictionaries = jsonDictionary["items"] as! [[String : Any]]
        for pvDictionary in pvDictionaries {
            let newPlayView = PlayView(pvDictionary: pvDictionary)
            playView.append(newPlayView)
        }
    }

    return playView
}
```

}

I want to get the URL from tableview when user clicked.

I want to get an URL when click the Tableview then save it and pass it to the another tableview.

I can do this in JAVA but i am failed to convert in SWIFT 3

here is my java Example

```
 itemView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            resultp = data.get(position);
            Intent intent = new Intent(context, FragmentDemoActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("videoId", resultp.get(Main.VIDEO_ID));
            context.startActivity(intent);
            // Get the position



        }
    });
    return itemView;
```

Can anyone help me please?

Comment: And I guess you already override prepareForSegue?

Comment: i did it. but i can not get & pass the data @Larme

Comment: Where did you override it? What’s your code?

Comment: @Larme i edited my question with my code

Answer (score 2):

You need to implement `prepareForSegue` method

```
   override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath:
    IndexPath)
   { 
       tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true)

       performSegue(withIdentifier: "secondView", sender: indexPath.row)

   }    
   override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {

    var next = segue.destinationViewController as! PlayTableViewController

    next.indexOfCell = sender as? Int

 }
```

//

```
 class PlayTableViewController:UITableViewController
 {
       var indexOfCell:Int?

 }
```

Comment: i edited my question. can you please explain where i can edited the code? I need to get the URL , & pass the url in my next controller View

Comment: please help me brother

Comment: replace it with the name of the VC you want to navigate to also declare a var index inside it to hold the sended value

Comment: Value of type 'UIStoryboardSegue' has no member 'PlayTableViewController' now it's shows that. Can you please check again my question. I am edited it again @Sh_khan

Comment: not getting brother :( can you please give me the full code please

Comment: brother please answer please help

Comment: see copy paste the 2 methods in answer and replace **as! nextVC** with **as! PlayTableViewController**

Comment: override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        
        var next = segue.PViewController  as! PlayTableViewController
        
        next.index = sender as? Int
    }

Comment: **segue.destinationViewController as! PlayTableViewController** ,,,,,,,,,,,,  var next = segue.PViewController as! PlayTableViewController is not correct

Comment: Cannot assign to property: 'index' is a method @Sh_Khan

Comment: it's working but how can i pass the URL value? @Sh_Khan

Comment: send the whole model objcet to PlayTableViewController

Comment: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1r3G7s8CwLq8LMKYF1QPuf_Xr7eLMH4Uu

here is the full project @Sh_khan

Comment: sorry to disturbing you brother but any update? @Sh_Khan

Comment: Brother any help ??

Comment: how to replace this `let url2 = URL(string: "http://nix2.iotabdapps.com/apk/items.json")` line with new link??

Comment: brother any sollution?

Comment: send it as a parameter to **downloadAllEpisodes** method